# How can a find() access a document field for an operation? (MongoDB, nodeJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

hello I would like to know if daily_price > = price_clic * number_view

```
Model.find({

 daily_price: { 

  $gte: price_clic * number_view

 }

})
```

```
const schema = mongoose.Schema({

  price_clic: { type: Number, required: true },
  number_view: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  daily_price: { type: Number, default: 0 },

})
```

thank you so much

Comment: When using the document fields in a calculation you need to use `$expr` operator enclosing the aggregate operators `$gte` and `$multiply`.

Answer (score 1):

The following code solved my problem:

```
$expr: {

  $gte: [
    "$daily_price", { $multiply: ["$price_clic", "$number_view"] },
  ],
},
```